# Android Game on javascript

Tags: javascript, android, android-layout

I want to create a truth or dare game for android. I am actually thinking about a UI which will have a bottle which can be rotate when user allow it to. 
**my question is can i do it in android javascript ?** 
because i know js little bit and there might be some code available online related to my work.
any suggestion or code related will be appreciated 
Thanks

Also can i use javascript libraries like jquery on android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/start/) for developing might help you with your project. and yes phonegap does support jquery for android development.

Comment: Thank you so much brother. kindly give me more help about my application of possible. like how can i rotate bottle.

Comment: well you can always use html5 and javascript to develop the graphics. also [impactJS](http://impactjs.com/) is a good option.
while developing using phonegap you are just developing a web app and building it for a mobile platform. so if you have ever creating a game using JS before, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: will images will be automatically scaled in phonegap like android do for activities.

Comment: you could dynamically program your code to fit to the screen like [this](http://uihacker.blogspot.in/2011/01/android-phonegap-scale-webview-to-fit.html)